# Error installing Geneland

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm trying to install Geneland from local file, but the following message appears to me:

```
* installing *source* package 'Geneland' ...
** package 'Geneland' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs

*** arch - i386
Warning: execução do comando 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB="Geneland.dll" SHLIB_LIBADD='$(FLIBS)' OBJECTS="alarousset.o ggfstat.o hz.o main.o wrapper.o"' teve status 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'Geneland'
* removing 'C:/Users/Gabriel/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Geneland'
Warning messages:
1: execução do comando '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/i386/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Gabriel\Documents\R\win-library\3.4" "C:/Users/Gabriel/Documents/R/Geneland_4.0.6.tar.gz"' teve status 1 
2: In install.packages(files[tarballs], .libPaths()[1L], repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/Gabriel/Documents/R/Geneland_4.0.6.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Do you have [Rtools](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) installed and available in the path? If `Sys.which("gcc")` does not return a path that contains something like  `Rtools\mingw_64\bin\gcc.exe`, it is not installed or installed correctly.